# Re-arranging a derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

If $T = \sqrt { \frac {2h} {g} }$ and $x(t) = \frac {1} {2} gt^2$.

Could someone kindly explain to me how $$ \frac {dt} {T} = \frac {dx}{gt} \sqrt{ \frac {g} {2h}} $$

I'm currently struggling with Griffiths *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*. This worked example is on p. 10 of the 2nd edition.

Answer (score 2):

From the first equality $$\color{red}{\frac{1}{T} = \sqrt{\frac{g}{2h}}} $$ From the second equality $$ dx = gtdt \implies  \color{red}{dt = \frac{dx}{gt}}$$ Multiply the red equalities to get $$\frac {dt} {T} = \frac {dx}{gt} \sqrt{ \frac {g} {2h}}$$

Comment: Thank you. HNY.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dx}{dt}=gt$ so $\frac{1}{gt}\,dx=dt$. Dividing by $T$, we obtain
$$\frac{dt}{T}=\frac{dx}{gt}\cdot\frac{1}{T}=\frac{dx}{gt}\sqrt{\frac{g}{2h}}\,.$$

Comment: Thank you kind stranger.